# How do I transfer the data in my JTextField to a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

So we're supposed to be making a reservation screen for our Airline. After the user inputs his/her information and clicks on Reserve my code needs to show her the information back in on a separate frame. I have the frame set up, I just need to transfer the information IN the JTextField to the frame on JLabel. I heard I need to make it into a variable so I can use it in multiple places. I'm new to Java so please don't use words I might not be familiar with. Thank you and here is my code. I have 3 classes.

First Class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class TicketMan {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Airport");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TicketManBot panel = new TicketManBot();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); }    }
```

Second Class:(The class the fields are on.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class TicketManBot extends JPanel {


private JLabel name;
private JLabel dest;
private JLabel depc;
private JLabel dept;
private JLabel seat;
private JButton b;


Random rand = new Random();

private JTextField namef, destf, depcf, deptf;


public TicketManBot()

{



name = new JLabel ("Enter passenger's name:");
dest = new JLabel ("Destination: ");
depc = new JLabel ("Departure city: ");
dept = new JLabel ("Departure time: ");
seat = new JLabel ("Seat Number: " + rand.nextInt(100));

b = new JButton ("Make Reservation");

b.addActionListener (new results());
// the fields I need to move
namef = new JTextField (10);
destf = new JTextField (10);
depcf = new JTextField (10);
deptf = new JTextField (10);        

 add (name);
 add (namef);
 add (dest);
 add (destf);
 add (depc);
 add (depcf);
 add (dept);
 add (deptf);
 add (seat);
 add (b);


 setPreferredSize (new Dimension(200, 300));
 setBackground (Color.gray);         
}
private class results implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    int  resultLabel;

    String text = namef.getText();      

    JFrame results = new JFrame("Thank you for flying with JJ Air"); 
    results.setVisible(true);
    results.setSize (200, 300);
 // I need to move the fields up there in front of these VVVVVV
    JLabel nr = new JLabel ("Name of the passenger:");
    JLabel dr = new JLabel ("Destination:");
    JLabel depr = new JLabel ("Departure city:");
    JLabel dpr = new JLabel ("Departure time:");
    JLabel sr = new JLabel ("Seat number:");
    JLabel t = new JLabel ("Thank you for flying with us");
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    results.add(panel);
    panel.add (nr); 
    panel.add (dr);
    panel.add (depr);
    panel.add (dpr);
    panel.add (sr);
    panel.add (t);
}
}
}
```

Third Class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class results extends JPanel {

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: `" I'm new to Java so please don't use words I might not be familiar with."` -- could you list the words you might not be familiar with? Perhaps better would be for you to simply ask for clarification of any answer that confuses you. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jLabel.setText(jTextField.getText());
```

Where jLabel is your label and jTextField your text field.

For example:

```
JLabel nr = new JLabel ("Name of the passenger:"+Namef.getText());
```

You should read up on the Java coding style guidelines by the way, it will help make your code more readable to others.

Comment: But where exactly do I add that?

Comment: For example I need what the user types in "Namef" to be shared with "nr" after the name of the passenger. Can you show me an example. I'm really bad at this. Sorry

Comment: I just added your example to that part of the code and it says namef cannot be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do your coding for you. Based on what you posted above it should work, you need to check the variable name, etc all matches up.

Comment: That's my problem. I don't know how to get a variable name.

Comment: never mind I got it. Thank you. in your example you had Namer, it was actually namer.

Answer (score 0):

Jlabel is the label you want to set text to. jtextField is the tetxfield you want to get info from

```
jLabel.setText(jTextField.getText());
```

Also what you could do, is maybe gather all info from all textFields into Array and then use it to display whatever from array in desired jLabel. Or even better use Array to display data in nice looking Table :)

Comment: But where exactly do I add that?